# Unable to start a VM as a non-root user? Complains about the dac security driver?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, centos

I have a VM on a CentOS KVM server.  If I try to start the VM as a non-root user, I get the error:

```
$ virsh create VM.xml
error: Failed to create domain from VM.xml
error: unsupported configuration: Unable to find security driver for model dac
```

However, if I perform exactly the same action as root, it works perfectly.

It looks like a permissions or path problem, but I can't figure out what's triggering the error.

The security label info from the XML config reads as follows:

```
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='selinux' relabel='yes'>
    <label>system_u:system_r:svirt_t:s0:c162,c320</label>
    <imagelabel>system_u:object_r:svirt_image_t:s0:c162,c320</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
  <seclabel type='dynamic' model='dac' relabel='yes'>
    <label>+1000:+1000</label>
    <imagelabel>+1000:+1000</imagelabel>
  </seclabel>
```

The "1000" in the XML above is the uid from /etc/passwd for the affected user.  I've also tried it with the uid for the qemu user, but that made no difference.

Anyone seen this before?  I've found cases where folks are getting the error referencing the selinux driver, but I haven't been able to find any other instances where the error's complaining about the dac driver.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.

The security driver DAC is not available for non-root users as it's used to modify resource ownership on the system.

Remove the `<seclabel model='dac'..></seclabel>` part from your domain (`virsh edit`).